# cloud 7 php url rewriting, with htaccess have tried every single thing, i have not tried committing suicide

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

here is my case

im not in anyway good with regexp, i avoid it like its a disease
i have gone through every result on google, now im searching on gooding "how to commit suicide and die quickly" please i really need your help
i need a the extension removed and the query string rewritten

such that `www.example.com/story.php?pcord=$1` ->will look like `www.example.com/story/%1`

please when i mean `%1` i wouldn't like pcord to resurface on the url

for instance i want`www.example.com/story.php?pcord=4849AAS84` should look something like

`www.example.com/story/4849AAS84`

here is the code i have tried using but doesnt work atall, only removes the extension

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 Turn mod_rewrite on
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /


 ## hide .php extension snippet


 # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

 # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Well.  That escalated quickly ;)

Comment: Yeah, they didn't get the spacing right in front of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For `.htaccess`**

Here we're capturing the value from the Query String as `%1`, then we're rewriting a relative url that starts with `story.php` to a folder called `story` followed by our captured string. Then we're adding the `?` to the end of the new directive to stop the default nature of [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to perform `[QSA]` (Query String Append) on a string where we're not creating a new query string. To make it a permanent rewrite add the `[R]` flag:

```
#External Redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pcord=([A-Za-z0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^story.php story/%1? [R=301,L]
```

If you need to make it magically send the var back to the original string, then you need to capture it in the reverse way. ***Note:* Here you would NOT use the [R] flag because that tells the browser to redirect.**:

```
#Internal Forward
RewriteRule ^story/([A-Za-z0-9]+) story.php?pcord=$1 [L]
```

Remember if you've already tried using the `[R=301]` directive, it's likely cached in your browser.

Now, in PHP you should be able to access `pcord` with `$_GET['pcord']`.

The final code for `.htaccess` would be this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#External Redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pcord=([A-Za-z0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^story.php story/%1? [R=301,L]

#Internal Forward
RewriteRule ^story/([A-Za-z0-9]+) story.php?pcord=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^story
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Create the External Redirect for all existing .php files that are not story.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ $1/ [R=301,L]

#Create the internal forward that maps them back in hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @Absoluteer    thanks for you quick response , this is the first time i am making progress... the url rewrites but page is like a homeless god that has no food (the css all my css styling is gone.) i also think js might be gone aswell. please help

Comment: please my friend also if you remember the question has two dimensions, on all urls , i generally need to get rid of the .php at the end :D

Comment: i fixed the css issue... just changed the url of the css in story.php to relative url ...from style.css -> http://mysite.com/style.css

Comment: @ChukwubuikemBlazeUbah Never had to do that before, but I guess that would work? The last section?